# How to populate Dictionary using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

```
public class Person
{
     public string Email {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}

public Report : Dictionary<string, string>
{
     public Report()
     {
         List<Person> list = getData(); // filled with Person's
         var realList = list.Where(x => x.Name != "test");
         foreach( var i in realList)
         {
              this.Add(i.Email,i.Name);
         }
     }

}
```

I tried to simplify my code to get down to the question. Basically I have a list of Persons and I want to get a sub list of that and then for each element in the sub list I want to add it to this dictionary which is the class.

My question: Is there a way to get rid of that foreach statement and achieve the same effect with in the linq statement above. Because it seems silly to me to go through  the list once and then through the sub list. So what would be good if during the linq statement if x.Name is not equal to test then it adds it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My question: Is there a way to get rid of that foreach statement and achieve the same effect with in the linq statement above. Because it seems silly to me to go through the list twice

You don't go through the list twice in your code - the list is only enumerated once, as LINQ uses deferred execution.  This is likely the best way to achieve this.

If you didn't subclass a dictionary, however, and encapsulated one instead, you could use `ToDictionary` to create the encapsulated dictionary:

```
List<Person> list = getData(); // filled with Person's
Dictionary<string,string> people = list
                                     .Where(x => x.Name != "test")
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Email, x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Come to think of it, you could write `getData().Where(...)`. Assuming, of course, that `list` isn't used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Okay yeah at first I was editing someone else's code. So i don't know why they inherited the dictionary class. They had a nested for loop. So with what I have seen I am thinking of not inheriting dictionary and just using simple injector and then I can use a linq command to do everything in one search through the list.

Comment: @Beastwood Yeah - I wouldn't inherit dictionary unless you have a really good reason to do so, at which point encapsulation is probably better anyways... Just build the dictionary as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are some nice answers already here how to convert your list directly to a dictionary, they don't really answer the original question, *because you can't re-assign the `this` variable* (for classes it is read-only in C#) and you will have to iterate over the newly created dictionary to add elements from it to your `this` dictionary.

I usually solve this problem by materializing the LINQ expression to a List and using `ForEach()` method of the list (that also accepts lambda-expressions) to populate another structure.

Here isthea sample code:

```
     list
        .Where(x => x.Name != "test")             // your condition
        .ToList()                                 // turns expression to list
        .ForEach(a => this.Add(a.Email, a.Name)); // populating dictionary
```

You can have several conditions before `ToList()` invocation, just in case you want to exclude the values that are already in the dictionary.